# How to translate liveagent.findOrCreate() call to LiveAgent API ChasitorInit payload?

Tags: api, liveagent, chat

My client is implementing a custom chat that at some point hands over to Salesforce Chat by means of calling the LiveAgent APIs. In the ChasitorInit call it's possible to define `prechatDetails` and `prechatEntities` in such a way that when creating the LiveChatTranscript objects it creates or relates existing records of different objects. The documentation on how to actually use those objects to achieve record creation or relation is sparse. In the client's use case, they wanted to have the ability to relate the LTC to an existing Case.

While it's hard to figure the necessary payload out, this task is trivial when using the LiveAgent widget:

```
liveagent.addCustomDetail("Case Id", "5002600000RZjJNAA1");
liveagent.findOrCreate("Case").map("Id","Case Id",true,true,true).saveToTranscript('CaseId').showOnCreate();
```

However, when examining the ChasitorInit request generated by the widget, it comes up with blank `prechatDetails` and `prechatEntities`.

So how would one translate the above code into the configuration objects for the ChasitorInit request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When examining the Network tab of the DevTools of the chat popup I noticed that before the ChasitorInit request, the widget sends a request to an undocumented `/prechatVisitor` endpoint that has its payload encoded in the URL.

The payload's `endpoint` parameter value contains a URL that in turn contains parameters such as `det` and `ent`.

I ran this request's URL through `decodeURIComponent()` and got arrays that I could plug into the ChasitorInit request: `det` to `prechatDetails` and `ent` - to `prechatEntities` and it worked just like with the LiveAgent widget.

For the described use case, the values are as follows:

```
{
  "det": [
    {
      "entityName": "Case",
      "saveToTranscript": "CaseId",
      "showOnCreate": true,
      "linkToEntityName": "",
      "linkToEntityField": "",
      "entityFieldsMaps": [
        {
          "fieldName": "Id",
          "label": "Case+Id",
          "doFind": true,
          "isExactMatch": true,
          "doCreate": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ent": [
    {
      "label": "Case+Id",
      "value": "5002600000RZjJNAA1",
      "displayToAgent": true,
      "entityMaps": [],
      "transcriptFields": [],
      "doKnowledgeSearch": false
    }
  ]
}
```